# Get the current path of file executing module code

Tags: python

I have a `here.py` that gets the nearest folder name:

```
import os
def here():
    return os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

I have `app.py` which imports `here.py` and calls it:

```
from this_app.somewhere import here
print(here.here())
```

Finally, this is my folder structure:

```
this_app
  ├ __init__.py
  ├ app.py
  └ somewhere
    ├ __init__.py
    └ here.py
```

So you can see when I run `app.py` it will print `somewhere` because it is executing code in `here.py`

I want to keep the code in `here.py` but make it print out the folder `app.py` is in. In otherwords, I want to print the folder of the file that imported the module instead of the folder where the module is located, even though I want the code that decides what to print to be in the module.

I hope that makes sense. **Basically, how do I change `here.py` so that when I call `app.py` it prints `this_app` (that is, it prints the folder name of wherever `app.py` is located)?**

(One last consideration: my actual use case is more complicated than this so it can't resort to the current working directory because I might start the app.py from a directory far away from any of this. It has to be relative to the file that imports the here module, namely `app.py`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__file__` attribute is defined per-module. You need to pass the `__file__` of the calling module to `here`

here.py

```
import os
def here(calling_path):
    return os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(calling_path))
```

And use it:

```
from this_app.somewhere import here
print(here.here(__file__))
```